# Menu not showing on mobile (portrait mode)

Tags: wordpress, button, mobile, menu, themes

I have a Wordpress site with TheGem Theme installed. It's a beautiful theme, but on mobile, the menu (hamburger icon) doesn't appear if the phone is portrait oriented. If I rotate the phone in landscape mode, menu button is at it's place.
How can I solve the problem? If you need some code from theme files, ask me.

Comment: Which theme you are using? If hosted please provide url.

Comment: https://themeforest.net/item/thegem-creative-multipurpose-highperformance-wordpress-theme/16061685

Comment: And my site: http://cse.pedabt.ro

Comment: Ok, let me check and get bach to with the answer if possible.

Comment: Your site is not opening at my end, unable to check.

Comment: Site is on and there is not a hosting problem. I can acces the site so I don't know why you can't. http://cse.pedabt.ro/